# Navigation not working for new list items Ionic

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am new to Ionic so my question might be basic. I am implementing an application using tabs and lists. My navigation works for the first time I load the application. i.e. I can click on the first 10 list items and it navigates me correctly to a single page with some more details.

However upon loading more data using infinite scrolling, the navigation fails to work properly from the 11th item to the rest I can navigate but no details are displayed in the page I navigate to. Below is my code so far.

In my controller

```
.controller('AllAdsCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$state', function ($scope, $http, $state) {
      $scope.allads = [];
            $http.get("http://locahost/android/getAdsForIonic.php")
                .success(function(data){
                    $scope.allads = data;
                    console.log($scope.allads.length);
                    $scope.clickedad=$state.params.adId;
                    $scope.last = $scope.allads[$scope.allads.length-1].id;
                    //console.log($scope.last)
                })
                .error(function() {
                $scope.allads = "error in fetching data";
        });
                 console.log("out"+$scope.last)
      $scope.loadMore = function() {

        $http.get('http://localhost/android/getAdsForIonic.php?startHere='+$scope.last).success(function(items) {
          console.log($scope.allads.length);
          //console.log(JSON.stringify(items));
         $scope.allads = $scope.allads.concat(items);
         $scope.clickedad=$state.params.adId;
          $scope.last = $scope.allads[$scope.allads.length-1].id;
          $scope.$broadcast('scroll.infiniteScrollComplete');
        });
      };
}]);
```

In my route I have

```
.state('tab.detail', {
      url: '/home/:adId',
      views: {
        'tab-home': {
          templateUrl: 'templates/ad-detail.html',
          controller: 'AllAdsCtrl'
        }
      }
    })
```

In ad-detail.html I have

```
<ion-header-bar class="bar-positive">
<h2 class="title">Ad Information</h2>
</ion-header-bar>
<ion-view>
  <ion-content class="padding">
  <ion-list class="list-inset" ng-repeat="ad in allads | filter : {id : clickedad}">
  <ion-item class="item-text-wrap">
      <h2>Title : {{ad.title}}</h2> 
    <img ng-src="http://localhost/{{ad.image_path}}" width="100px">
      <h2>Price : {{ad.price}}</h2> 
     <p>
      <h3>Description : {{ad.description}}</h3> 
    </p>
    </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Where did you use `<ion-infinite-scroll..` and `ng-click` or `ui-sref` on `ion-item` for the navigation. Could you add full code of **ad-detail.html**

Comment: you have a typo loca-host in `$http.get`